# How do I place a filled border around text using css?

Tags: css, border

I have a text title on my site but it doesn't stand out due to the background. Does anyone know how to place a filled 'border' around the text like in the screenshot? Preferably with curved edges as per the screenshot also. I've googled around but I get the feeling i'm not hitting the right search query.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: not sure what a filled border is but you can do the above with background colour and border-radius

Comment: can you please your html and css code here

Comment: @Pete 10 points to you sir! This has worked perfectly thank you